# How Do I ask my boss that I need a two week leave for preparing for higher studies?

Tags: work-environment, job-change

I am planning for Fall'17, and I am already running late, I am planning to give GRE / TOEFL in coming two weeks and require leave for that. These two weeks are extremely important to me, can you guys suggest me how do I ask for leave for the same?

Comment: Why didn't you ask several weeks ago?

Comment: It was a sudden and abrupt decision, I was always planning for MS but then I was not sure about it.

Comment: Wasn't all that important then

Comment: Are you working part-time or full time? Is your job an internship?

Comment: It's my full time job

Answer (score 2):

Two unshakable facts:

1. As a full timer, you are entitled to consume any unused vacation and personal time.
2. The catch is that your management has to approve your vacation, because they have to take steps to minimize the disruptive effect of your absence.

Your problem at this point is that you are asking for two weeks of time off on VERY short notice.

Your chances of getting your leave approved improve if you can show that you have taken steps to minimize the disruption caused by your absence, say by rounding up people to cover for you, by stating a willingness to show up in the office to deal with emergencies, by promising that you'll be reachable at all tomes by email and by willing to compromise and take less than two weeks off, if it comes to that. You may offer to cover for the Jewish holidays if you are not Jewish and your management is. On my first full-time professional job, the management loved to have me around because as a Buddhist and single person I could be counted to cover for the firm on any and all Christian and Jewish holidays. Including Christmas Day.

It is really important that you can show your management that they will be taken care of during your absence, as you are asking practically at the last minute - and you don't want any taint of irresponsibility attached to your request for time off. Your absence as a professional from the line up is a big deal to management, so treat it like a big deal.

I have no idea what other objections your management might have to your asking for time off at the last minute but make sure you identify those objections and are prepared to meet those objections. You are trying to sell your management on you taking time off and they may be extremely reluctant buyers. And they won't buy before you meet their objections.

Answer (score 0):

Most employers are supportive of higher studies in theory. However you did nothing to prepare for this.

You need to be upfront asap. I would do this in person if I were you. Make what lame excuses you can and you'll probably be fine. You might get leave without pay, so be prepared for that.

Comment: I am not worried about leave without pay, all that I was worried about is, can I ask for it straight forward or shall I give some other excuse for leave?

Comment: Straightforward is always best, anything else is risky.

Comment: "Some other excuse" So you mean lie? Anything but what you want it for is a lie, unless you use the broad "personal reasons" reason which is fine but don't except any understanding of the short notice